# Accessing protected members of another class

Tags: c#, class, friend, access-modifiers

I have one class A, from which I need to access protected members of class B, in the same manner that one would use the friend keyword in C++. However, the internal modifier does not suit my needs. Class B will need to create an instance of class A, modify its private data, and return a reference to that class. Those class A members will need to remain private to the original caller.

```
public class A
{
    protected int x;
}

public class B
{
    public static A CreateClassA()
    {
        A x = new A();
        x.x = 5;   // ERROR : No privilege
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried redesigning your self out of that nightmare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to either create a public setter for the `protected` field or inherit from the class.

```
public class A
{
    protected int x;

    public int X { set { x = value; }  }
}

public static A CreateClassA()
{
    A x = new A();
    x.X = 5;
    return x;
}
```

Or:

```
public class B : A
{
    public static A CreateClassA()
    {
        this.x = 5; 
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a field, not a property: setter does not apply

Comment: @MarcGravell - Yes, my mistake. But adding a public setter for the field should be OK, no?

Comment: This will work, but you turned the field into a public field for all practical purposes.

Comment: @zmbq - this may be exactly what the OP was looking for (the field value cannot be read outside the class and its inheritors).

Comment: The second block doesn't compile

Answer (score 7):

You can use `protected internal` instead of `internal` to give access to all classes in the same assembly, as well as subclasses in other assemblies:

```
public class A
{
    protected internal int x;
}

public class B
{
    public static A CreateClassA()
    {
        A x = new A();
        x.x = 5;   // hurray
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The question is a bit old at this point but here's another method, doing what you ask, without lectures or finger-wagging:

Consider:

```
A foo = new A();
FieldInfo privateField = foo.GetType().GetField("x", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
privateField.SetValue(foo, 5);
```

Warning: Use of the above code breaks encapsulation, curves your spine and may cause ear damage from the shrill screaming of OO purists.

...but it works great for factory classes, compensating for C#'s lack of a friend keyword.

Warning 2: This is slow.

Answer (score 3):

You should check official MSDN Friend Assembly.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx
By that example you could do:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("AssemblyB")]
public sealed class A
{
    internal int x;
}
```

And from assembly B set/call internal methods/fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   public class A
   {
      protected int x;

      public class B
      {
          public static A CreateClassA()
          {
              A x = new A();
              x.x = 5;   // ERROR : No privilege
              return x;
          }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Will a class B exist for every class A that is created?

Comment: No as long as it is static. Correct me if I am wrong. I use this kind of classes for building complex objects. Something like. SomeObject.Builder().DoSomething(). Where SomeObject = A, Builder = B, DoSomething = CreateClassA

Comment: What if you just leave the 'public class B' part? So class A contains a 'public static A CreateClassA()' (not really a good name, it creates an instance of Class A, not ClassA itself). I guess that would do the trick too

Comment: It depends on how complex is the object. If it is only one field then static factory method is OK. But when you have variations of several components then a class is far better choice.

Comment: I don't think class B is created until you instantiate it. I use this without the static modifier, when you need access to A protected (or even private) members, without exposing a concrete method/property in A. Is like having an extension from A, but you only need to create B when is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access protected members, if you inherit from A. You can now either:

- Inherit from A
- Make a public method setX(int newX) which sets the value of X.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but having a public Set() method that the caller could utilize could upset the functionality of class A, since it is essentially read only data. Inheritance would not make any sense from the perspective I am using it, and I hope that's not the only option.

Comment: If you want that field to behave immutable, add a constructor to class A which receives it as argument.

Comment: That's a nice one. In this way, x can only be set once from outside the Class A family. Note that classes that inherit from A are still able to change the value after an instance of A has been made.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative:

```
public class A
{
    public A() { }

    public A(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    protected int x;
}

public class B
{
    public static A CreateClassA()
    {
        A x = new A(5);
        return x;
    }
}
```